# Squid Proxy AD Authentication

Tags: linux, active-directory, squid

I've done a lot of searching but i cannot seem to find a free solution. I need a web proxy to monitor the websites visited by each active directory user. I used NXFilter but HTTPS is not working for it's login page (captive page). I think squid can accomplish this but I cannot find a good documentation for AD integration. The guides available use deprecated packages. I know I am not an expert on linux but I did not expect this to be this hard.

Can anyone help a bro out?

Comment: What distro are you on?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: I think all needed packages (`(squid)_ldap_auth` etc.) are in the official repos or installed with squid? What is the problem?

Comment: how do i integrate AD with squid?

Answer (score 0):

It might be of some help - see AD integration instruction for Kerberos from https://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_7_0/active_directory/index.html. 
In short - create a specific user in AD, generate keytab on Windows Domain mapping that user name to Squid's SPN and configure squid to use that keytab.

Comment: Thanks but i am lost in step 4 in this guide. I tried following the steps in installing Web Safety but i got a bunch of errors. I will try using the VA in this site and see how it goes.